# Recover File Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

So, here's my case: I do have a Writer file, in this Libreoffice Writer file, I copied a few tables from Libreoffice Calc(I actually did this for 6 hours) and pasted on Writer. When I went to see my file, there was a lot of tables that weren't there anymore. I do believe this happened after I renamed both files. Is there anyway I could recover those images/tables? Or how can I see where this images are linking? I tried to look on the Trash, rename again those files, But I simply can't find it. I have a lot 'empty images' on my file. I would not like to lose another 6 hours copying again.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6652/how-to-recover-former-version-of-document/), you will want to look at `Tools → Options → LibreOffice → Paths → Backups` for the path. Then look fora relevant .bak file in that folder.

However, this assumes you have had the `Tools → Options → Load/Save → General` setting `Save AutoRecovery information every...Minutes` checked.

If you didn't have the auto saver you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Yep, I was definitly out of luck. in this ocasion I've done again, the whole thing.

Comment: @CarlosParisotto If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.